# What causes the JNI error "use of deleted local reference"?

Tags: java, android, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I have an Android app where the following C method is called when the app starts (in `Activity.onCreate`).

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_google_oboe_test_oboetest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject instance) {

    jclass sysclazz = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
    jmethodID getPropertyMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(sysclazz, "getProperty", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring result = (jstring) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(sysclazz, getPropertyMethod, "os.name");
    return result;
}
```

When this method is called the app crashes and I get the error:

**JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0xd280e8d5**

Step debugging shows that this line causes the crash:

```
jstring result = (jstring) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(sysclazz, getPropertyMethod, "os.name");
```

What causes this error? And how can I call `System.getProperty("os.name")` using JNI without getting this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that `env->CallStaticObjectMethod` is expecting a `jstring` as its 3rd argument and is instead being supplied with a string literal.

Creating a `jstring` first

```
jstring arg = env->NewStringUTF("os.name");
jstring result = (jstring) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(sysclazz, getPropertyMethod, arg);
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Remember to free those `jstring ` variables using `DeleteLocalRef` for example, `env->DeleteLocalRef(arg);` and `env->DeleteLocalRef(result);` or else you will have a memory leak inside your code.

Comment: @shizhen: Not necessary since `stringFromJNI` will return back to java, which automatically clears the local references that have been created.

Comment: Theoretically it is true that you let JVM to release those local refs for you. But, it would be more like a "best practice" to delete the local references which are created by your code. Because, the local references will consume a lot of JVM resources especially when you create/use it inside a long loop, excessive allocation of local references may cause the VM to run out of memory during the execution of a native method. For this case, it is so simple that it may not really matter much. Of course, this is really up to yourself whether you want to do this.

Comment: Some references: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#DeleteLocalRef
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni

Comment: @shizhen There are no long loops in the OP's code, and no reason whatsoever why he should even consider deleting local references, especially when his question is about an apparently *already*-deleted local reference.

Comment: @EJP, Yes, as I said, it does not really matter a lot for this case,  this case is too simple to tell the importance of delete a local reference as early as possible. The point I want to make here is to keep this coding practice in mind.

Comment: I have a native functionA created jstring jstr1 to do sth and then deleteLocalRef(jstr1) before return. However, when I 2nd times use native functionA again, debugger reported that java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x105.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a local reference that was created in a function and was used in another function.
For example:

```
void funA(){
    jclass localClass = env->FindClass("MyClass");
}
```

The above statement returns a local reference of jclass. Suppose we store this in a global variable and use it in another function `funB` after `funA` is completed, then this local reference will not be considered as valid and will return "use of deleted local reference error".

To resolve this we need to do this:

```
jclass localClass = env->FindClass("MyClass");
jclass globalClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(localClass));
```

First, get the local reference and then get the global reference from local reference. `globalClass` can be used globally (in different functions).

Read [Local and global references](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#local-and-global-references)